# Get content in same div jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, onclick

I've got a gallery on my website with each of them a unique ID. I'm trying to get this idea to work:
Click on the first image = the content of first image. Click on the second image = the content of second image.. etc etc.

Currenlty i've set each image with a unique id as seen below:

```
echo "<img src='http://bsc.ua.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/white-placeholder-100x100.jpg' data-original='$thumbnail[0]' width='$thumbnail[1]' height='$thumbnail[2]' class='lazygallery' id='$thumb_id'/>";
```

And with jQuery i can get all content in the screen, one for one. So if I click img1 I get content 1.

Got 2 loops, one for the thumbnails and one for the content:
Thumbnail:

```
echo '<div class="gallery">';
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post($post->ID);
$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'gallery-thumb', true, '');
$thumb_id = get_the_ID();
echo "<img src='http://bsc.ua.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/white-placeholder-100x100.jpg'  data-original='$thumbnail[0]' width='$thumbnail[1]' height='$thumbnail[2]' class='lazygallery'  id='$thumb_id'/>";
endwhile;
echo '</div>';
```

The content loop is almost the same but then just other functions in side it (like the_content(), and a bunch of custom stuff).

My script currently:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<?php echo $thumb_id ?>').on('click', function () {
            var idimg = $(this).attr('id');

            alert('Id: ' + idimg);
            $('.content_<?php echo $thumb_id ?>').toggle();

        });
    });
</script>
```

**Full Question**
**How can I get the script too work like this:
Img1 gets clicked - show Content1
Img2 gets clicked - empty the div, then set Content2
Img3 gets clicked - empty the div, then set Content3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first need to make a 'display' div which is always visible.

E.g.:

```
 <div id="information"></div>
```

With CSS such as this:

```
 #information {
     position:fixed;
     margin-top:50px;
     margin-left:50px;
     background-color:grey;
 }
```

This div will display the information of the images we click on.

Now to actually update this div with the information, we do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#<?php echo $thumb_id ?>').on('click', function () {
         // get the correct content id
         var idimg = $(this).attr('id');
         var contentId = '.content_' + idimg;  

         // update information div
         $('#information').html($(contentId).html());
     });
});
```

Comment: I tried this :     $('.content_<?php echo $thumb_id ?>').html(idimg.html()); but does not work. Am i doing it wrong? im kinda new to this so sorry  :p. You do know that each "content_$thumb_id" class starts with "display:none;" ?

Comment: Try setting `var idimg = $(this);` (so remove the `.attr('id')` part) and then put in `alert(idimg.html())` and tell me what happens.

Comment: I spotted the error: your PHP is wrong. The `$('.content_<?php echo $thumb_id ?>')` returns things like `$('.content_ 920')`. Do you see the space there? That shouldn't be there.

Comment: Good find, but still nothing :(

Comment: Empty again

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<?php echo $thumb_id ?>').on('click', function () {
                var idimg = $(this);
                alert(idimg.show().html());
                $('.content_<?php echo $thumb_id ?>').html(idimg.html());

            });
        });
    </script>

Comment: @R3dn0l: See updated answer. Try that. If all your PHP is correct, that should work.

Comment: Hmm. it works, but places the timeline kinda weird. But i think i can manage to fix that. Thanks

Comment: So, I needed a div, but when i put css in it it breaks. So left it empty and now all works. Or is this a bad idea?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. If you put CSS in it, it doesn't work? That doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Yeah if I put css like this ;     background-color:#b1b4b5;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:75px;
    margin:auto;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    /*Chrome, Safari, Opera*/
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    /*Firefox*/
    column-count: 2;

in the #information, whole website gets ruined but doesnt matter. Only thing thats not ok is that lazyload isn't working anymore.. maybe you can check it out? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037937/lazyload-not-working-properly